# How to get selected values in an array and pass the others to a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

Copy the uncorrupted data in the array stored in targetDisk to the empty array newDisk (corrupted data looks like this: ø). Then print the contents of the disk to the terminal as a string.

```
var targetDisk = [ 'E', 'ø', '-', 'C', 'ø', 'o', 'r', 'ø', 'ø', 'p', '\'', 'ø', 's', ' ', 'E', 'v', 'ø', 'i', 'ø', 'ø', 'l'];
var newDisk = [];
var corruptionSymbol = 'ø';


for ( i=0; i < targetDisk.length; i++;){


if (targetDisk[i] !== corruptionSymbol);{

      newDisk.push (targetDisk[i]);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var targetDisk = [ 'E', 'ø', '-', 'C', 'ø', 'o', 'r', 'ø', 'ø', 'p', '\'', 'ø', 's', ' ', 'E', 'v', 'ø', 'i', 'ø', 'ø', 'l'];
var corruptionSymbol = 'ø';
var newDisk = [];

for (var i = 0; i < targetDisk.length; i += 1) {
  if (targetDisk[i] !== corruptionSymbol) {
    newDisk.push(targetDisk[i]);
  }
}

console.log(newDisk.join(""));
```

Comment: I just start learning this days and am doing some exercises, where i jump to next question only after answer the previous one. And we have talked about .pop/.push and split. So I only can use this methods.

Comment: Ok, I changed codeto your requirements

Comment: Thanks a lot Mero, but its not working the way they ask.

Comment: Is it possible to do in some other way and get the result they ask, because they say is the wrong output.

Comment: I made small changes in print, take a look)

Comment: You are great Mero, all this time they was asking for this... Thank you a lot

Comment: You welcome, if we finished - mark this answer as complete

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve it by using [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Live Demo **:**

```js
let targetDisk = [ 'E', 'ø', '-', 'C', 'ø', 'o', 'r', 'ø', 'ø', 'p', '\'', 'ø', 's', ' ', 'E', 'v', 'ø', 'i', 'ø', 'ø', 'l'];

let corruptionSymbol = 'ø';

const newDisk = targetDisk.filter(item => item !== corruptionSymbol);

console.log(newDisk);
```